# Image change but cannot see it in heroku's folder

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm facing this strange behaviour. Maybe, it's normal in `heroku`. In my app I have an image folder located in `img/uploaded`. Everything is ok in my application, I do see the image. But when I connect to `heroku` via `heroku run bash` and go to the same folder my file is not there. Any idea why is this? Maybe `heroku` takes some time to update folders/files.

My system is in `symfony2.6` if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your image file is missing when you inspect the file system with "heroku run bash" is that Heroku creates a separate [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) when you execute that command. The file system you are inspecting is different than the one accessed by the requests coming from your browser.

If you start using more than one dyno assigned to a web worker, you'll want to use an asset store to make sure your files are accessible by all your dynos. You can also take a look at Heroku's article about the [Read-only filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem).

Comment: Ohh. I see. That makes sense. I'm probably create a AWS Amazon S3 account and set up a bucket for my assets files. As this guide says https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3